# Users Level in restricted area to trigger different contents

Tags: php

I am creating a login system and the idea I have is when someone logins , an if statement will check the user level, and for each level it will run a different code , something like

```html
if ( row['userLevel']== 2 ) {

// here comes the whole page


};
if ( row['userLevel']==1 ) {


// here comes the whole page in a different way

}
```

or should I use only one page , and evrytime I need to load something specific to a level I use the if statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends how different your pages are surely? If they are completely different, I would do it as you are currently doing it. If they are almost the same then I would use one page and change the content where necessary.

Comment: I see,  and there are no security flows in both ways right ?

Comment: There can be security flows both ways.

Comment: Well that depends how you write it. I can't guarantee you won't introduce a security flaw, but there is no reason to expect one way would be any more secure than the other.

Comment: @spencer7593 then its another subject it seems, any advice ?

Comment: @Chris I see, I should give an eye on some security tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't that depend on your aims? If there are two different pages, i.e. an admin page, it may be useful to detect early the permissions of an user. Otherwise, you will produce duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other comments.

And i think this way is better

```
// 0 = User
// 1 = Moderator
// 2 = Supermod
// 3 = Admin

    if ( row['userLevel'] >= 1 ) { 
    echo "This page can see for: mod, supermod and Admin.";
     }
    if ( row['userLevel'] >= 3 ) { 
    echo "This page can see for: Admin.";
     }
```